# Filesystem Mechanism to Complement MongoDB in .NET program

Tags: c#, .net, database, mongodb, filesystems

I'm relatively new to databases, so I'm trying to find a good filesystem mechanism that can work with MongoDB. Ideally, I'd use GridFS, but I don't generally care too much for files breaking into many little pieces and being put back together. I'd also like to keep MongoDB as lean as possible for better performance.

After doing some Googling (although probably not searching for the right things), I haven't had much luck finding anything meaningful for a good filesystem mechanism in a .NET database program that complements MongoDB's .NET API.

As far as I know, I can simply have the directory of the file on a field in MongoDB as a string, but I'd like to know of possible standards or commonly used mechanisms for secure filesystem upload and download (Whether its Linux, Windows, or a standalone server-client system, etc).

Can you recommend anything?

Comment: Do you actually need to store the files in a DB?  Links to S3 buckets or other online (secure) file systems might be easier to manage.

Comment: @Neil -- Thanks for your quick response. I would prefer to have the files saved on the same server as the MongoDB Server's host, if possible. I would like to avoid using any third party cloud servers, in case there is a confidential (or even proprietary) nature to the files being saved.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you having a local/relative path of some kind that would map the links in the db to the files.  If it's a Linux server, then you could have some input over the file types vs the file system.

Comment: Hi, @Neil -- Do you recommend any sort of .NET platform for doing that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  .NET Core runs on Linux, if that's what you mean?  I've worked on a system that did basically this, although the files were stored on a local SAN, there were links stored in the Postgres DB to the files, but really, any DB would do the job just as well.

Comment: Hi, @Neil -- sorry I wasn't clear before. What I mean is -- is there a singular and universal platform that has a good .NET API that can grab a raw file from any local or remote server? Is there anything that does it securely and quickly? Some end-to-end encryption would also be nice.

Comment: As long as the file is reachable on the local file system (either mapped to / on Linux or as a Window share), then simple `File.Open` would do the trick.

Comment: Hi, @Neil -- What if the file is on a remote (not necessary a cloud) server?

Comment: If the file is on a local network (SAN or similar) then it can be mapped to a local share.  If it's anywhere on the internet, then it makes no difference if it's a cloud or not.  You can always use https or ftps or sftp to transfer the file.  ftp is well supported via nuget packages, https would probably work with `File.Open`.